# LoadError: no such file to load -- openssl/dummy

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to run a jruby application. Whenever I start the jruby script, the app throws out an error which says

> LoadError: no such file to load -- openssl/dummy    (root) at
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/jruby-openssl-0.8.2/lib/shared/jruby-openssl.rb:15
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027    (root) at
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1
>        each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613   require at /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72
>        each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613   require at /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70
>   require at
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59
>   require at
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027   require at
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
>   (root) at /home/ubuntu/apps/autocaller/config/application.rb:13
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027   require at
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
>   (root) at /home/ubuntu/apps/autocaller/script/autocall.rb:17

jruby verion is 1.7.3
ruby version is 1.9.3p385
How do I fix this issue. I am fighting to fix this issue since many days. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

```
Run a bundle update to upgrade jruby-openssl to 0.9.4.
```

Comment: `Code formatting is for code only. Please don't put normal text in it.`